# App crashes due to "Application exited abnormally with signal 9" or"Application exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault" in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, segmentation-fault, sdwebimage

In my iPhone app am using lots of images and loading into tableview. I am using SDWebimage. When scrolling am getting either "Application exited abnormally with signal 9" or "signal 11: segmentation fault".How to resolve this issue. Please help!!!

Comment: Is there any specific details you can give? Like code going in, error details, debug messages?

Comment: @CBredlow: am getting the following report in console.  <Warning>: Application 'xxxxx' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault
 <Error>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2012-12-20-120633.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0

Answer (score 0):

the watchdog kills you because you consume too much memory. Try handling didReceiveMemory warnings

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Not the only thing that can do it. If your applicationDidFinishLaunching: takes too long, watchdog can kill you for that too.

Comment: @occulus yes but that doesn't fit this question -- a) he has a lowMem error, b) it isn't at start time

Answer (score 0):

The iOS watchdog is killing your app. This mechanisms terminates your app under certain conditions, including:

- **free memory becomes too low**
- your app takes too long in crucial parts, e.g. startup time

For more info, please read:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1693/_index.html

http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Quote from 2nd link:

> What Generates a Crash Log?
>
> There are two main situations that can result in a crash log: Your app
>   violates OS policies. There are bugs in your app. iOS policy
>   violations include things such as watchdog timeout at the time of
>   launch, resume, suspend and quit; user force-quit; **and low memory**
>   **termination**. Let’s go over these in more detail...

Comment: Free memory being too low sounds like it might be something to do with this question.